# what could be the reason I am getting java.net.UnknownHostException, when I try to ping my own pc with a network IP?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, unknown-host

I try to ping the server which is my own PC, with the following line of code :

```
InetAddress.getByName(serverResourceLocator).isReachable(5000)

// where serverResourceLocator is  192.168.43.187/server/ping?ip=Adarsh-PC/192.168.43.187&time=1355482205301
```

Here `192.168.43.187` is the network IP of my PC, that I came to know from the command `ipconfig`

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f5be:cfa7:5c38:efff%14
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.187
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

On my PC i am running tomcat as the server. Why am I getting `UnknownHostException` ?

---

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.43.187/server/ping?ip=Adarsh-PC/192.168.43.187&time=1355482205301
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1140)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1109)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1072)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:969)
at internet.CommunicationWithServer.PingTheServer.ping(PingTheServer.java:35)
at internet.CommunicationWithServer.PingTheServer.access$000(PingTheServer.java:11)
at internet.CommunicationWithServer.PingTheServer$1.run(PingTheServer.java:21)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [.getByName() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) expects a hostname, not a (semi-)URL as you are supplying. To quote from the JavaDoc:

> The host name can either be a **machine name**, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its **IP address**. If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.

(My emphasis).

Just try `InetAddress.getByName( "192.168.43.187" ).isReachable(5000)` and you'll be fine.

It occurs to me that you have written a servlet that will ping an IP. If it eg. returns the latency via the HTTP response, then you should use eg. the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) package to programmatically obtain that response; there are several threads on SO on accomplishing that.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

`serverResourceLocator` is more like an URL, whereas [`InetAddress.getByName`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) requires a hostname:

Try

```
InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.187").isReachable(5000)
```

Comment: but i have to ping to a servlet that will handle everything. what can i do about this

Comment: That would be a HTTP request to that servlet, not a network ping.  Try something like [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to simplify making the HTTP request, but that would be a different question.